# How to create a global variable in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm doing a loop inside my template, well, i want verify if my actual object is equal the object that comes before this.

This is my tamplate code:

```
    {% for i in format_data %}
        <li>
            {% with first=i %}
                {{forloop.counter}}
                {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}

                    <table class="format-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td data-format-id="{{i.format_name.id}}">{{i.format_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.field_name}}</td>

                            {% if i.field_format_data %}
                                <td>{{i.field_format_data}}</td>
                            {% else %}
                                <td>Campo não preenchido</td>
                            {% endif %}
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                {% elif second == first %}
                    <table class="format-table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{i.field_name}}</td>

                            {% if i.field_format_data %}
                                <td>{{i.field_format_data}}</td>
                            {% else %}
                                <td>Campo não preenchido</td>
                            {% endif %}
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                {% endif %}
            {% endwith %}
            {% with second=i %}
            {% endwith %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

What I want is set a variable in the final of the loop that receive this actual object and in the next time that loop works, verify if the actual object is equal the last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a global variable in a template, and really you should avoid trying to create variables there at all.

If you want to check a value between iterations, you can use the [`cycle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) tag.